# How to remove this panel from Adobe Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I am beginner in Illustrator, whenever I try to select a shape or anything on my artboard this panel keeps popping up. Can anyone help to turn this thing off and also explain what is its function?

Answer (score 5):

That indicates **Isolation Mode**.

Simply **click the little arrow** there and you will "back out" of Isolation Mode.

You can also use the **Selection Tool** (Black arrow) and **double-click anywhere on the artboard** to exit Isolation Mode.

If it "keeps popping up" you may be mistakenly *double-clicking* objects. You *enter* Isolation Mode via a double-click on something.

**Double-clicking to enter Isolation Mode can be disabled entirely in the preferences.**

[image]

Comment: how about pressing `esc` :)

Comment: Originally ESC didn't do anything. They added it later. But you're right.. that is easier `:)`